# associating a principal $G$- bundle for a $G$-torsor?

Tags: differential-geometry, connections, principal-bundles

I see the line "a $G$-torsor is a principal $G$-bundle" many times.

I am trying to see how they are related. You are welcome to take your own definition of principal $G$-bundle.

Definition of $G$-torsor that I am familiar with is as follows :

> Let $G$ be a Lie group. A $G$-torsor is a manifold $X$ with a free and transitive action of $G$.

I do not have any idea how to associate a principal $G$-bundle $(P,M,G,\pi)$ with this. Should I take $P=X$? But the action of $G$ on total space of a principal bundle is in general not transitive. Only transitive action I see in a principal bundle is the action of $G$ on fibers $\pi^{-1}(x)$.

So, fixing a principal $G$-bundles $\pi:P\rightarrow M$, I am **not** getting just one $G$-torsor but a collection of torsors $\{\pi^{-1}(x)\}$ indexed by elements of $M$.

So, I **do not** think a $G$-torsor gives a principal $G$-bundle. But, a collection of $G$-torsors $\{P_m\}$, indexed by elements of a manifold $M$, **might** give a principal $G$-bundle over $M$, if these are glued together. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two notions of torsor, or there is the notion in the definition you gave (aka principal homogeneous space), and also a relative version (and more generally a categorical version). The relative version intuitively means that the fibers are principal homogeneous spaces, plus a local triviality condition.

See the section about this in Wikipedia's article [principal homogeneous space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_homogeneous_space#Other_usage) under other usage.

Since relative versions of things are so common in algebraic geometry, its not surprising to see the more general notion at the article [Torsor (algebraic geometry)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsor_(algebraic_geometry)), while "Torsor" redirects to the page for principal homogeneous space.

Comment: So, it is only about the notation... There is a notion of torsor (definitive version) and a notion of torsor on a manifold (relative version).. This relative version over a manifold M is same as principal bundle over M is what you are saying. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah that's right it's just the (more general) definition of $G$-torsor. The most general version replaces the group $G$ in "$G$-torsor" by a group object $\mathcal G$ in a category $\mathcal C$. Principal $G$-bundles on $X$ are a special case of this generalization when the category is objects over $X$ (aka the slice category); in this case the group object is the trivial/constant $G$-torsor $\mathcal G = X\times G$ with the projection map.

Comment: Can you also write down the generalisation in your answer... A $\mathcal{G}$-torsor over $X$ where $\mathcal{G}$ is a (sheaf of groups?) over $X$... please add three definitions in your answer just for reference...

Comment: I am not using \mathcal to denote sheaves, just objects in categories. In this case $\mathcal G$ was meant to denote the object $X\times G \to X$ in the [slice category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_category)

Comment: Ok. That is also fine. Please add those (and any other versions of torsor) in your answer,,

Comment: The definitions are, roughly in order of increasing abstraction/generality, are available at (1) wikipedia: principal homogeneous space, (2) wikipedia: principal bundle, (3) wikipedia: torsor (algebraic geometry), (4) nlab: torsor